# How can I console.log functions alongside all their properties?

Tags: javascript

I'm using the Google Chrome console. Frustratingly, the following code

```
var f = function () {};
f.a = 1;
console.log(f);
```

will only log

> function () {}

Why does it not print the properties of `f`, such as `f.a` and `f.prototype`? How can I print them?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Try `console.dir`.

```
console.dir(f);
```

Answer (score 3):

`console.dir` lists all the defined properties of an object. I think this is probably what you're looking for.

**How this appears in FF (Firebug)**

[image: console.dir in Firebug]

**How this appears in Chromium's console**

[image: console.dir in Chromium]

I'm not sure if there's any Chrome documentation on this functionality, but [there is Firebug documentation](http://getfirebug.com/wiki/index.php/Console_API#console.dir.28object.29) on the `console` object.

Answer (score 0):

<s>Because a function is not an object.</s>

If you do:

```
var f = function () {};
var my_instance = new f();  // aha!
my_instance.a = 1;
console.log(my_instance);
```

You should get what you expect.

<s>A function *can* be a class, but never an object. Use `new`.</s>

Comment: Wrong. A function *is* an object.

Comment: JavaScript functions are objects (they are "first-class"). There is no problem with assigning a property to a function (`f.a` in the question). It's a good way to emulate static fields in JavaScript. In your example, the `a` property will only be present on the `my_instance` instance.